# Converting raster layer to simple feature in R

Tags: r, sf, st-geometry

I have read my raster data using

```
r <- raster("F:\\Studies\\Whole2015.tif")
class(r)
> class(r)
[1] "RasterLayer"
attr(,"package")
[1] "raster"
```

How can I transform my data to simple feature?

I want to use a function named `st_geometry`, which can only be used to `sf` object.

Comment: `st_geometry` gets or sets the geometry from an existing simple features object. It doesn't really do anything interesting itself. What do you want to do with the data once you've converted it? What does your raster look like? Is it points, lines, or polygons? Please edit your question with more details and if possible an image.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Following https://r-spatial.github.io/stars/articles/stars5.html#vectorizing-a-raster-object-to-an-sf-object yo can do it with `stars`, although the question is not completely clear for me:

```r
library(stars)
library(sf)

tifpath=system.file("tif/L7_ETMs.tif", package = "stars")
tif=read_stars(tifpath)
sf=st_as_sf(tif)
sf
#> Simple feature collection with 122848 features and 6 fields
#> geometry type:  POLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: 288776.3 ymin: 9110729 xmax: 298722.8 ymax: 9120761
#> epsg (SRID):    NA
#> proj4string:    +proj=utm +zone=25 +south +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
#> First 10 features:
#>    L7_ETMs.tif.V1 L7_ETMs.tif.V2 L7_ETMs.tif.V3 L7_ETMs.tif.V4 L7_ETMs.tif.V5
#> 1              69             56             46             79             86
#> 2              69             57             49             75             88
#> 3              63             52             45             66             75
#> 4              60             45             35             66             69
#> 5              61             52             44             76             92
#> 6              61             50             37             78             74
#> 7              62             51             41             76             79
#> 8              60             51             37             78             80
#> 9              64             51             39             68             67
#> 10             63             52             49             70             84
#>    L7_ETMs.tif.V6                       geometry
#> 1              46 POLYGON ((288776.3 9120761,...
#> 2              49 POLYGON ((288804.8 9120761,...
#> 3              41 POLYGON ((288833.3 9120761,...
#> 4              38 POLYGON ((288861.8 9120761,...
#> 5              60 POLYGON ((288890.3 9120761,...
#> 6              38 POLYGON ((288918.8 9120761,...
#> 7              43 POLYGON ((288947.3 9120761,...
#> 8              38 POLYGON ((288975.8 9120761,...
#> 9              32 POLYGON ((289004.3 9120761,...
#> 10             53 POLYGON ((289032.8 9120761,...
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I have just seen @Spacedman, fully agree